# Swap list item according to multiple parameters

Tags: c#, list, sorting, swap

I have a list like the one below. I want to sort this list according to the rule I specified. If there is an element to which the list element is attached, it must be in the front row.

For example, since the RequiredCourse field of the record with Id 2 is 3, the element with Id 3 must come before the element with Id 2. To do this, I created a swap method as follows. But the record with Id 3 depends on 4 and I couldn't create the sorting properly. Additionally, it depends on 10 with Id 8 and below. But 9 is not connected to anything. Since I changed the place of the records with id 8 and 10, 8 goes after 9.

The sample output should be as follows:

```
        var list = new List<Course>();

        list.Add(new Course { Id = 1 });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 2, RequiredCourse = "3" });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 3, RequiredCourse = "4" });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 4 });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 5 });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 6 });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 7 });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 8, RequiredCourse = "10" });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 9 });
        list.Add(new Course { Id = 10 });
        list = list.OrderBy(i => i.Id).ThenBy(i => i.RequiredCourse).ToList();

        var copy = new List<Course>(list);

        for (int i = 0; i < copy.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(copy[i].RequiredCourse) && Int32.Parse(copy[i].RequiredCourse) > copy[i].Id)
            {
                var index = list.FindIndex(k => k.Id == Int32.Parse(copy[i].RequiredCourse));
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    var temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[index];
                    list[index] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

*Defective Output using code above*

```
1                
3                4
4                
2                3
5                
6                
7                
10               
9                
8                10
```

*Expected Output*

```
1                
4                
3                4
2                3
5                
6                
7                
10               
8                10
9
```

Comment: What about situation when for example a course with id 1 has a required course with id 2, but a course with id 2 has a required course with id 1?

Comment: No such condition like that. 2 cannot be depends on course 1 .A course can only be linked to a course with an Id greater than itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is easy enough to understand.

```cs
var list = new List<Course>();

list.Add(new Course { Id = 1 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 2, RequiredCourse = "3" });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 3, RequiredCourse = "4" });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 4 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 5 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 6 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 7 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 8, RequiredCourse = "10" });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 9 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 10 });

var output = new List<Course>();
var toProcess = new SortedDictionary<int, Course>(list.ToDictionary(c => c.Id));
var pendingAdd = new Stack<Course>();

while (toProcess.Count > 0)
{
    Course currentCourse = toProcess.First().Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentCourse.RequiredCourse))
    {
        // Course has no dependency, process it.
        output.Add(currentCourse);
        toProcess.Remove(currentCourse.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        int courseId = currentCourse.Id;
        // Course has dependency. Trace down linked courses.
        while (toProcess.ContainsKey(courseId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toProcess[courseId].RequiredCourse))
        {
            pendingAdd.Push(toProcess[courseId]);
            courseId = int.Parse(toProcess[courseId].RequiredCourse);
        }
        // dont forget to add the "top-level" course for the dependency chain
        pendingAdd.Push(toProcess[courseId]);

        // Add in reverse depdency order using Stack
        while (pendingAdd.Count > 0)
        {
            var course = pendingAdd.Pop();
            output.Add(course);
            toProcess.Remove(course.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Your wanted list is in `output`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want the item "2 - 3" below the "4 - ''". I'm sure there's a way to improve what I've done, but here's version 1.0:

```cs
var list = new List<Course>();
    
list.Add(new Course { Id = 1 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 2, RequiredCourse = "3" });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 3, RequiredCourse = "4" });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 4 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 5 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 6 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 7 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 8, RequiredCourse = "10" });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 9 });
list.Add(new Course { Id = 10 });

// isolating items with RequiredCourse
var withRequired = (
    from o in list
    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.RequiredCourse)
    select o
).ToList();
list = list.Except(withRequired).ToList();

// First I arrange the items without "RequiredCourse" with their respective ones.
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var primary = list[i];
    var parents =
        withRequired
            .Where(o => o.RequiredCourse == primary.Id.ToString())
            .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
            .ToList();
    var children = (
        from o in withRequired.Except(parents)
        join o2 in parents
            on o.Id.ToString() equals o2.RequiredCourse
            into grp
        from o3 in grp
        orderby o3.Id descending
        select o3
    ).ToList();

    if (!parents.Any())
    {
        continue;
    }

    i++;
    foreach (var p in parents)
    {
        list.Insert(i++, p);
        foreach (var c in children.Where(o => p.Id.ToString() == o.RequiredCourse))
        {
            list.Insert(i++, c);
        }
    }
}

// retrieving items that only link to items that have RequiredCourse
var childOfChildren = withRequired.Except(list).ToList();

// Then I arrange items with RequiredCourses that are linked to other items with RequiredCourses.
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var primary = list[i];
    var children = (
        from o in childOfChildren
        where primary.Id.ToString() == o.RequiredCourse
        orderby o.Id descending
        select o
    ).ToList();

    if (!children.Any())
    {
        continue;
    }

    i++;
    list.InsertRange(i, children);
}

// CONSOLE APPLICATION PART
foreach (var o in list)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.RequiredCourse))
    {
        o.RequiredCourse = "-";
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Course: {o.Id} - {o.RequiredCourse}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with regression , sample code not tested for other case . only tested for given data .

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Course>();

    list.Add(new Course { Id = 1 });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 2, RequiredCourse = "3" });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 3, RequiredCourse = "4" });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 4 });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 5 });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 6 });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 7 });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 8, RequiredCourse = "10" });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 9 });
    list.Add(new Course { Id = 10 });
    list = list.OrderBy(i => i.Id).ThenBy(i => i.RequiredCourse).ToList();

    var copy = new List<Course>();
        
    foreach(var tt in list)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(tt.Id + " " + tt.RequiredCourse);
        populateParent(list,ref copy, tt);
        
        if(!copy.Any(p => p.Id == tt.Id))
            copy.Add(tt);
    }
    
    foreach(var tt in copy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tt.Id + " " + tt.RequiredCourse);
    }
}

public static Course populateParent(List<Course> inputList,ref List<Course> outputList, Course current)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(current.RequiredCourse))
    {
        if(!outputList.Any(p => p.Id == current.Id))
            outputList.Add(current);
        return current;
    }
    else
    {
        var tt = inputList.First(p => current.RequiredCourse != null && p.Id == int.Parse(current.RequiredCourse) );
        
        var parent = populateParent(inputList,ref outputList,tt);
        if(!outputList.Any(p => p.Id == parent.Id))
            outputList.Add(parent);
        
        if(!outputList.Any(p => p.Id == tt.Id))
            outputList.Add(tt);
        return tt;
    }   
}
```

[code in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7HEgiF)